# Upgrade 64-bit machine running 32-bit ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, 64-bit

I have a 64-bit machine. Way back, over a decade ago, when I first installed Ubuntu, the 32-bit version was recommended, so that is what I installed. I have kept it upgraded and have had no problems at all. Nice system.

Now I want to upgrade to 20.04. What do I do?

I don't want to be stuck due to a decision that was *recommended*!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a Live disc of 20.04 or 20.10 to make sure it works with your machine.  Use `usb-creator-gtk` if you want to use it with USB.

If the Live disc doesn't work on your system... upgrade or downgrade to 18.04.  That should give you a few years to figure out how to get 64-bit Ubuntu working on your system or find another distro that works.

If the Live disc checks out...

- Boot back into your 32-bit system.
- Save a list of packages on your system: `apt-mark showmanual > packages.txt`
- Backup `/opt`, `/etc`, `/home`, and any other folders that might have data you want to save.
- Boot the Live disc to install the 64-bit system.

  - Let the installer format `/`.
  - If `/home` is on a separate partition, you can leave it alone.
  - It *should* be safe to use the same home directory, but you may choose to create a new one.  It's up to you.
- Boot into the installed system (now 64-bit).  Use the package list to install packages.  You might have to edit the list to get this to work properly.

  ```
  sudo apt install `cat packages.txt`
  ```

  Or look through the list to pick out packages you want to install separately.
- When reconfiguring the system, use `/etc` backup as *reference*, but *don't* just copy it over.

Comment: I started with version 11.04. I never made the change to 64-bit because (1) people wrote that it was horrendously difficult, and (2) 32-bit was working fine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I was using 64-bit before 2009. I'd characterize it as mildly inconvenient. To run 32-bit programs, you have to install i386 libraries. I think the biggest problem was getting Flash to run in 64-bit browsers. But then they released a 64-bit version, and now it's gone.

Comment: Result -- I followed your directions EXACTLY and it worked well. The 'apt install' failed, but I just manually installed the packages I needed, no problem. I copied in my entire saved /home, and nearly everything worked fine. Firefox needed a little tweaking. The whole procedure took less than a day. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Recommendations change over time.

The pool of Ubuntu contributors who run 32-bit desktops has shrunk. There are now too few 32-bit Desktop contributors to test, troubleshoot bugs, and provide support.

Feel free to recruit more 32-bit Desktop contributors. There's no rule or policy that 32-bit Desktops are being abandoned forever.

The only decision so far is that Canonical won't replace those missing community contributors with it's paid engineers. The *result* of that decision is that nobody is making 32-bit Desktop releases anymore. That result can be changed with more community involvement.

Ubuntu 18.04 32-bit is still fully supported until 2023, so you have some time to start organizing and contributing toward the (hypothetical) 22.04 release.